# Mount LevelOne GNS-2000 NFS share on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, nfs, nas

I'm trying to mount a LevelOne GNS-2000 NFS share, but whatever options I try, it fails.

```
showmount 172.16.3.84 -e
Export list for 172.16.3.84:
/harddisk/volume_1/data/public *
```

I tried the following without success:

```
mount -t nfs 172.16.3.84:/harddisk/volume_1/data/public nas
mount -t nfs 172.16.3.84:/harddisk/volume_1/data/public nas -o nfsvers=3
```

...as well as every combination of paths, partial paths, `-t nfs`, `-t nfs4`, `tcp`, `udp`, `port=2049`, and adding `/export/`.

When I specify `nfsvers=3`, I get:

```
mount.nfs: mounting 172.16.3.84:/public/ failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory
```

If it is omitted or set to `nfsvers=2`, it just hangs there.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount it by the name you given the share:

```
mount -t nfs "172.16.3.84:/DISK 1" nas
```

e.g. for the default share